# ErrorException : failed loading cafile stream: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt', en Dusk laravel

Tags: laravel, dusk

Tengo un proyecto en `laravel 5.7.*` para el cual instale `laravel/dusk=5.7.*` y se instalo correctamente el comando fue:

```
composer require laravel/dusk=5.7.*
```

Despues ejecute:

```
php artisan dusk:install
```

El cual me voto el error:

> ErrorException  : failed loading cafile stream: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente cambiando de versión de `laravel\dusk` pero no encuentro la solución. La versión mas actual me dice que la versión de laravel no es soportada.

A que se debe este error? como debo de solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue difícil de encontrar pero fue la siguiente:

Reemplace la linea **249** del archivo `chromeDriverCommand.php`

```
 return file_get_contents($url, false, $streamContext);
```

Por:

```
 return file_get_contents(str_replace('https:', 'http:', $url), false, $streamContext);
```

luego ejecute:

```
 php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 72
```

y el resultado fue bueno:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego ejecute:

```
 php artisan dusk:install
```

Este comando aun dio el error que indique en la pregunta. Pero las pruebas funcionan correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL post original lo encuentran aqui: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/770#issuecomment-625495556